# How to know if user can edit/delete user in MS Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a single page app that uses the Microsoft Graph API to manage users.
We use only delegated permissions.

I would like to hide the Delete User button if the user does not have permissions to delete users.
But it doesn't seem there is a way for the app to know until we try to delete.

So is there any way to know if the user can do this action?
I'm kind of on the side of *no, you cannot know in advance*.
But I am wondering if I am just missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing a memberOf query to Microsoft Graph API, which returns all the user's groups and directory roles. I check if they have User Administrator or Global Administrator role, and decide on that if they can edit and delete users.

It's a little suboptimal since we fetch groups too, but this is done only once after login. I tried filtering on roleTemplateId, displayName and @odata.type field but that is not supported.

If the memberOf query fails, I assume they cannot edit or delete users either.